# How to push an object while adding a property in one operation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I can push an array **and** amend extra elements to it in one, single operation like this.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let col = [];
col.push(arr);
col.push([...arr, 4]);
```

I wonder if it's possible to achieve something like that, a one-liner for amending and pushing, for objects.

```
let obj = { ... };
obj.extraInfo = "shazoo";
col.push(obj);
```

I haven't found anything so I'm prepared for no-go but I've been wrong before.

Comment: `col.push({ ...obj, extraInfo: 'shazoo' });`

Comment: By "amend" do you happen to mean "append"?

Comment: do you want to keep the original object or take a new one for pushing?

Comment: btw, for arrays, a new feature works with [`Array#with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with), which returns a new array with a single changed/new value.

Comment: @jcalz Well, sort of. Although, my English teacher always told me that *appending* is to the edge or end while *amending* is position neutral.   :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't care about the original one, as long as the old values plus the new one are present in the pushed instance. A bit like what Dave already answered.

Comment: "Amend" is position-neutral but has the connotation of fixing or improving something as opposed to just changing it.  If you don't care about position I'd say "modify" instead of "amend".

Comment: @jcalz Point taken.

Comment: Also I don't think "amend" or "modify" takes an indirect object, so you wouldn't say "amend element X to array Y" or "modify element X to array Y".  You *do* say "append element X to array Y" so that's why I thought it was "append".  Anyway, just trying to understand, I'll run away now instead of digressing further into grammar land

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `{...obj, extraInfo: "shazoo"}`:

```js
obj = { example: "demo" }
col = [];
col.push({ ...obj, extraInfo: "shazoo"});
console.log(col);
```

Or, if you need `obj` to itself be modified, you can do

```
 col.push(Object.assign(obj, {extraInfo: "shazoo"}));
```

Comment: I'm sure you know, but in this case `obj` is not modified, while `obj` is modified in the question. I can't tell what OP would want to happen to obj, but the difference is there.

Comment: That's true, updated with an alternative in case `obj` itself does need to be modified